# '14' is not a valid for value for property 'Style'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In the following xaml I create an error in the MainWindow xaml ('14' is not a valid for value for property 'Style'). I can still run the application, and strangely enough the style is visualized correctly at runtime.

```
<UserControl x:Class="PerfectCode.TVShowManager.UserInterface.Views.TVShowControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:PerfectCode.TVShowManager.UserInterface.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <GroupBox>
        <GroupBox.Header>
HERE I AM NOT ALLOWED TO SET THE STYLE ON MY TEXTBLOCK
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LargeText}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </GroupBox.Header>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Seasons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSeason}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SmallText}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <userControls:SeasonControl/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </GroupBox>

</UserControl>
```

When I do this anyway, I will have an error in my MainViewWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PerfectCode.TVShowManager.UserInterface.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PerfectCode.TVShowManager.UserInterface.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Manage your TV Shows" 
        Width="1500" Height="900">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <views:ActionBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
        <views:TVShowListControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
THE NEXT LINE HAS THE ERROR
        <views:TVShowControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" DataContext="{Binding SelectedTVShow}"/>
    </Grid> </Window>
```

The styles as requested in comments:

```
<Style x:Key="SmallText" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="LargeText" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
</Style>
```

As I said before, it all does work just fine. The app is visualized correctly. The header of the groupbox has all attributes of "LargeText" and is presented with Foreground color White.

When I remove the Style from the textblock, then, and only then the error disappears (after rebuilding).

I am using VS2015 and .NET4.6 (and R#9.2 if that has anything to do with it).

Am I doing something incorrect in XAML?

Comment: What values do LargeText and SmallText have?

Comment: Can you post your LargeText style definition, please?

Comment: @SaphuA and Il Vic, updated question

Comment: i cannot reproduce this issue it works fine

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh are you using VS2015 and .NET 4.6 as well? (thanks for helping out btw!)

Comment: no vs 2013 n .net 3.5